# A better way than using nested For-loops to make a search list

Tags: list-manipulation, functional-style

I'm generating a List that can be up to 26 values long, a simplified example is below. Is there a better way than nested loops?

```
 For[r = minr, r <= maxr, r = r + dr, 
   point[[1, 1]] = r;
   For[theta = 0, theta <= Pi, theta = theta + dthe, 
     point[[1, 2]] = theta;
     For[phi = -Pi, phi <= Pi, phi = phi + dphi, 
       point[[1, 3]] = phi; 
       val = myfunction[point]]]]
```

This really gets slow when I get ups to 5 nested loops.

Comment: It's great that you included your code, but could you also explain what you are trying to do? It's unclear why you're nesting loops at all, since the calculations inside the inside inner loops don't seem to reference the values in the outer loops. Furthermore, it seems like you keep assigning to `point[[1, 1]]` different values. So what exactly are you trying to do here?

Comment: As commented by march, please clarify your specific problem and  add additional details to highlight exactly what you need as an end result. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [How to Ask](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question and then [edit] your question to make it better.

Comment: It is the start of a grid search/error space mapping for a test function. I'm stepping through my solution space and will record the lowest and highest error at  each radius step.

Comment: So you are trying to maximize or minimize some function?

Comment: minimize, but the function is really nasty (takes about 3 hours with the minimization functions in Mathematica), I trying to get a quick estimate of the solution space to narrow down the domain.

Comment: Something got lost in the simplification -- your example code doesn't build a list.

Comment: It populates the point list, the real version is a recursive function call with one for loop,that passes a list. But the point was the loops are slowing down the data run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Table` should do the trick.

```
Table[myfunction[{r, theta, phi}],
   {r, minr, maxr, dr},
   {theta, 0, π, dthe},
   {phi, -π, π, dphi}
 ]
```

This will produce a nested list of `myfunction` values. You may need to use `Flatten` on the result depending upon the shape that you want for the output.

Comment: Thanks I will give it a try as soon as can get logged in.

Comment: Unfortunately, Mathematica wont let me us a list for the iterators part, and I would be stuck hard coding the Table. And how far out can you nest with Table?

Comment: @Phymonkey - Mathematica supports using a list as an iterator. For example, `Table[i, {i, {4, 7, 12}}]` produces `{4, 7, 12}`.

Comment: Ok, I was trying it a little different.

Answer (score 0):

Jack,I want thank you for your answer, it didn't give what I wanted but it was in the right direction. Here is the solution I have (one Do loop and a recursive function call) I could have done it with just one function but this was easier to debug, here are the functions:

```
Do[loop++; map[[loop]] = tablefunction[r, 2, inc, dim, range],
    {r, range[[1, 1]], range[[1, 2]], inc[[1]]}]

tablefunction[list_, index_, incr_, dim_, range_] := 
  Module[{map, nlist},
   If[index == 2,
    nlist = 
     Table[{list, ang}, {ang, range[[index, 1]], range[[index, 2]], 
       incr[[index]]}], 
    nlist = Partition[
      Flatten[Table[{list[[i]], ang}, {i, 1, Length[list]}, {ang, 
         range[[index, 1]], range[[index, 2]], 
         incr[[index]]}]], {index}]];
   If[index != dim, 
    map = exploremse[nlist, index + 1, incr, dim, range], 
    map = calculatemse[nlist]]; map];

It is about 4 times faster than the for loops but it will eat memory if dim gets over 5.
```